# Returning a function array with user's input contents into the UI using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, input

I have created a basic application with a working function array that is supposed to take a user's input, and return an array with their input as the last number in the array- replacing certain integers with strings in the process.

When I `console.log` something like `rangeOfNumbers((0,13));` it shows everything functioning properly. However, I have tried googling everything, looking at MDN, and sitting at my computer for hours trying to figure out how to implement my function into the UI so that it will print when the user hits submit, but I just cannot figure out what to do next or what I am doing wrong.

Console logging it works, but I don't understand why the user's input isn't being pushed into the end of the array automatically with the function. If someone could help this beginner out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the block of code in my scripts file that I am struggling with:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(start, numberInput) {
  let rangeArray = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= numberInput; i++) {
    rangeArray.push(i + "");
  }
  return rangeArray.map(x => x.includes("3") ? "Won't you be my neighbor?" : x.includes("2") ? "Boop" : x.includes("1") ? "Beep" : x);
}

// This is where I am having issues. Html matches up so I know it isn't that.
$(document).ready(function() {
  const numberInput = $("#numberInput").val();
  
  $("#formRobo").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").rangeOfNumbers(0, numberInput);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

Firstly, `rangeOfNumbers()` isn't a jQuery function. You've defined it yourself so you need to call it independently of jQuery and set the result to be displayed in the `#result` element. Assuming that's a `div` use `text()`, or if it's a form control use `val()`.

The second issue is that you only read the value of `#numberInput` when the page loads, so it's always going to be the default. To read the value the user entered before submitting the form you need to move that line *within* the `submit` event handler.

Try this:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(start, numberInput) {
  console.log(numberInput);
  let rangeArray = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= numberInput; i++) {
    rangeArray.push(i + "");
  }
  return rangeArray.map(x => x.includes("3") ? "Won't you be my neighbor?" : x.includes("2") ? "Boop" : x.includes("1") ? "Beep" : x);
}

// This is where I am having issues. Html matches up so I know it isn't that.
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("#formRobo").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const numberInput = $("#numberInput").val();
    $("#result").text(rangeOfNumbers(0, numberInput));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formRobo">
  <input type="text" id="numberInput" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! I can't believe it was that simple of a fix. MUCH appreciated. I've accepted your answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the text of the element.

```
$("#result").text(rangeOfNumbers(0, +$("#numberInput").val()));
```

If you want to allow your function to be called on `jQuery` elements, you can set it on `jQuery.fn` (`jQuery.prototype`).

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(start, numberInput) {
  let rangeArray = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= numberInput; i++) {
    rangeArray.push(i + "");
  }
  return rangeArray.map(x => x.includes("3") ? "Won't you be my neighbor?" : x.includes("2") ? "Boop" : x.includes("1") ? "Beep" : x);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formRobo").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").text(rangeOfNumbers(0, +$("#numberInput").val()));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formRobo">
<input id="numberInput" type="number"/>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text` method of jQuery instance.
Could you please try this:

```
$("#formRobo").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").text(rangeOfNumbers(0, numberInput));
});
```